# Validating Arbitrary Python Code

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an application that will take in a string and later run it as arbitrary python code.  I wish to validate this string before I attempt to run it and evaluate it for a few things:

1. Syntactically correct (this can be done via the `compile(stringCode, foo.py, "execute")` builtin)
2. All imports are available locally
3. Whether a class in the arbitrary code string inherits from a specific class
4. Whether the class from #3 also implements a specifically named method (so I can later call `foo.bar()` on the arbitrary code without too much hassle)

I've looked around at code objects, but they don't seem to be able to do anything unless I try to run the code directly, when I would rather validate that it works beforehand

Comment: This is *really* hard without running the code. Classes can be dynamically created and redefined, and the halting problem is also in the way.

Comment: Yeah, I figured this would be rough. Honestly, I'm just trying to be smarter about this than searching the program string for "import *" and then attempting the import.  

If the user wants to get weird with their class creation, then they can figure out the issue themselves. I'm just trying to do a sanity check and make sure that we have the obvious modules available and alert if they're trying to import something weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ast.parse` to create a syntax tree of your string. Then you can iterate over the tree and validate whatever parse-time qualities you like.

As internet_user says, this will *not* tell you about the run-time qualities of your code; if modules are imported through a mechanism other than the usual `import` statement, those won't be validated. If your classes are dynamically changed to add or remove methods, you won't know that just from looking at the `defs` in their class definition.

Provided that you're not worried about any of that, here's a sample implementation:

```
import ast
import sys
import os
import imp

s = """
import math, gzip
from os import system
import numpy
import obviouslyFakeModuleName

class A(int):
    def troz(self):
        return 23

class B(str):
    def zort(self):
        return 42
"""

def can_be_imported(name):
    try:
        imp.find_module(name)
        return True
    except ImportError:
        return False

def iter_nodes_by_type(code, type_or_types):
    for node in ast.walk(code):
        if isinstance(node, type_or_types):
            yield node

def iter_imported_module_names(code):
    for node in iter_nodes_by_type(code, ast.Import):
        for alias in node.names:
            yield alias.name
    for node in iter_nodes_by_type(code, ast.ImportFrom):
        yield node.module

def iter_globally_defined_classes(code):
    for child in ast.iter_child_nodes(code):
        if isinstance(child, ast.ClassDef):
            yield child

def iter_methods(class_):
    for node in ast.iter_child_nodes(class_):
        if isinstance(node, ast.FunctionDef):
            yield node

try:
    code = ast.parse(s)
except SyntaxError:
    print("That string is not valid Python.")
    sys.exit(0)

#inspection of imports
for name in iter_imported_module_names(code):
    if can_be_imported(name):
        print("module {} is available for import.".format(name))
    else:
        print("module {} is not available for import.".format(name))

#inspection of classes
for class_ in iter_globally_defined_classes(code):
    class_name = class_.name
    base_class_names = [name.id for name in class_.bases]
    function_names = [func.name for func in iter_methods(class_)]
    print("Inspecting class {}...".format(class_name))
    #we want to know if this class inherits directly from int
    if "int" in base_class_names:
        print("  Does inherit from int.")
    else:
        print("  Does not inherit from int.")

    #and does it implement zort()?
    if "zort" in function_names:
        print("  Implements `zort`.")
    else:
        print("  Does not implement `zort`.")
```

Result:

```
module math is available for import.
module gzip is available for import.
module numpy is not available for import.
module obviouslyFakeModuleName is not available for import.
module os is available for import.
Inspecting class A...
  Does inherit from int.
  Does not implement `zort`.
Inspecting class B...
  Does not inherit from int.
  Implements `zort`.
```

Comment: Wow. Just wow.  This looks about perfect. I'll definitely have to do some reading on syntax trees. They look like exactly what I'm looking to deal with.

I'll wait to see if anybody else puts out an answer, but this looks great.